Verifying PS512 JWT on Android not working
I use the default JWTs generated by https://jwt.io/. One using the RS512 algorithm and the same token using the PS512 algorithm. I'd like to verify the token using the provided public key in my Android app. Here are my gradle includes:
jsonwebtoken-api = { group = "io.jsonwebtoken", name = "jjwt-api", version = "0.12.6" }
jsonwebtoken-impl = { group = "io.jsonwebtoken", name = "jjwt-impl", version = "0.12.6" }
jsonwebtoken-json = { group = "io.jsonwebtoken", name = "jjwt-jackson", version = "0.12.6" }
bouncycastle-prov = { group = "org.bouncycastle", name = "bcprov-jdk15to18", version = "1.78.1" }
bouncycastle-bcpkix = { group = "org.bouncycastle", name = "bcpkix-jdk15to18", version = "1.78.1" }

    implementation(libs.jsonwebtoken.api)
    runtimeOnly(libs.jsonwebtoken.impl)
    runtimeOnly(libs.jsonwebtoken.json) {
        exclude(group = "org.json", module = "json")
    }
    implementation(libs.bouncycastle.prov)
    implementation(libs.bouncycastle.bcpkix)

The MainActivity replaces the "BC" security provider by:
    companion object {
        init {
            Security.removeProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
        }
    }

Here is the code for reading the public key (for test purposes stored as local variable):
    val publicKey:String = "..."
    private fun stringToPublicKey(): PublicKey {
        val parser = PEMParser(StringReader(publicKey))
        val converter = JcaPEMKeyConverter()
        val publicKeyInfo: SubjectPublicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(parser.readObject())
        return (converter.getPublicKey(publicKeyInfo) as RSAPublicKey)
    }

Here is the code for token validation:
val jwtPS512 = "..."
try {
    val parser = Jwts.parser().verifyWith(stringToPublicKey()).build()
    val test = parser.parse(jwtPS512)
    Log.i("", "$test")
} catch (e: Throwable) {
    Log.e("", "", e)
}

Here is the link to the full project example: https://github.com/artkoenig/JWT-Test
The validation works for the RS512 algorithm, but for the PS512 algorithm I get the following error:
io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.

Please let me know if I missed anything.

Fixed by forcing the BouncyCastleProvider() to be used by the parser by:
val parser = Jwts.parser()
  .provider(BouncyCastleProvider())
  .verifyWith(stringToPublicKey())
  .build()

see (https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/959)
